# Error when creating a SQL Server 2008 R2 database using VBS (SQL DMO)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldmo

I used to run a script in VBS using SQL-DMO to create a new database. This was done for SQL Server 2000 however this is no longer working under SQL Server 2008 R2.

Script is like this:

```
Const C_SQL_UID = "sa"
Const C_SQL_PWD = "sa"
Const C_SQL_SERVER = "dbserver"
Const C_SQL_TMPDBNAME = "TMP_DB"
Const C_SQLDIR = "d:\data"

Dim SqlServer: Set SqlServer = CreateObject("SQLDMO.SqlServer")
SqlServer.Connect C_SQL_SERVER, C_SQL_UID, C_SQL_PWD

Dim database: Set database = CreateObject("SQLDMO.Database")
Dim dbDataFile: Set dbDataFile = CreateObject("SQLDMO.DBFile")
Dim dbLogFile: Set dbLogFile = CreateObject("SQLDMO.LogFile")

database.Name = C_SQL_TMPDBNAME

dbDataFile.Name = C_SQL_TMPDBNAME
dbDataFile.PhysicalName = C_SQLDIR & "\" & C_SQL_TMPDBNAME & "_Data.mdf"
dbDataFile.PrimaryFile = True
dbDataFile.Size = 2
dbDataFile.FileGrowthType = 0 'SQLDMOGrowth_MB
dbDataFile.FileGrowth = 1

database.FileGroups.Item("PRIMARY").DBFiles.Add(dbDataFile)

dbLogFile.Name = C_SQL_TMPDBNAME & "Log"
dbLogFile.PhysicalName = C_SQLDIR & "\" & C_SQL_TMPDBNAME & "_Log.ldf"
dbLogFile.Size = 2

database.TransactionLog.LogFiles.Add(dbLogFile)

On Error Resume Next
SqlServer.Databases.Add(database)
If Err Then
    wscript.echo Now & " Error creating DB (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

When it executes the final instruction ("SqlServer.Databases.Add(database)"), I get the error number -2147219701 ... which doesn't contain any description. I'm not sure where it can comes from.
I know that Microsoft dropped the DMO thing, but since SMO doesn't support VBScript I'm kinda out of options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, in the end I just used a good old ADODB connections and made all the requests in T-SQL.
For this script it's simply :

```
Dim conn
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.CommandTimeout = 9999
conn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 10
conn.Open "server=" & C_SQL_SERVER & ";uid=" & C_SQL_UID & ";pwd=" & C_SQL_PWD & ";database=Master"

sql = "CREATE DATABASE " & C_DB_NAME & " "
sql = sql & "ON ( NAME = '" & C_DB_NAME & "', FILENAME = '" & C_SQLDIR & "\" & C_DB_NAME & "_Data.mdf', SIZE = 5MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) "
sql = sql & "LOG ON( NAME = '" & C_DB_NAME & "Log', FILENAME = '" & C_SQLDIR & "\" & C_DB_NAME & "_Log.ldf', SIZE = 5MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5MB )"
conn.Execute sql
```